# Construct a dynamic menu by selecting parameters with jQuery, php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive menu that could reconstruct itself by selecting a combination of parameters.

In the example below I've named the different menus so that they have things in common each is also unique. By choosing "all" then all menu items would appear; choosing "1's" and "B's" would only show "Menu item 1B. 2014; green"; choosing "2013" would show only menu items with 2013; choosing "green" would show only results with green; etc…

The menu as it is now targets an iframe and returns a hyperlink when clicked, which is a feature I'd like to retain. This seems like such a complicated problem to me, is there a way to filter results with jQuery or php? Essentially I think I'm trying to filter results through tags?

Any help on this would be amazing!

```js
(function() {
  $('.menu a.nav-tab').on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $('iframe').attr('src', href);
    $('.current-url').empty().append($('<a>').attr('href', href).append('"' + href + '"'));

    $('.menu a.nav-tab').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    return false;
  });
})();
```

```css
.hyperlinks {
  width: 200px;
}
.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.filter {
  width: 200px;
}
iframe {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hyperlinks">
  <p class="current-url"></p>
</div>

<div class="filter">
  View by:
  <br>
  <br>
  <a id="all" href="tab1">All</a>
  <br>
  <a id="1" href="website">1's</a> / <a id="all" href="website">2's</a> / <a id="all" href="website">3's</a>
  <br>
  <a id="all" href="website">A's</a> / <a id="all" href="website">B's</a> / <a id="all" href="website">C's</a>
  <br>
  <a id="all" href="website">2015</a>, <a id="all" href="website">2014</a>, <a id="all" href="website">2013</a>
  <br>
  <a id="all" href="website">blue</a>, <a id="all" href="website">green</a>, <a id="all" href="website">red</a>.
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>


<div class="menu">
  Menu:
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="nav-tab tab1" href="http://www.dictionary.com">Menu item 1A. 2015, blue</a> 
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab2" href="http://www.thesaurus.com">Menu item 1B. 2014, green</a> 
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab3" href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Menu item 1C. 2013, red</a> 
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab4" href="http://www.urbandictionary.com">Menu item 2A. 2015, blue</a>
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab5" href="http://www.hyperlink5.com">Menu item 2B. 2014, green</a>
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab6" href="http://www.electronics2000.co.uk">Menu item 2C. 2013, blue</a>
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab7" href="http://www.nytimes.com">Menu item 3A. 2015, blue</a>
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab8" href="http://www.theguardian.com">Menu item 3B. 2014, green</a>
  <br>
  <br>

  <a class="nav-tab tab9" href="http://edition.cnn.com">Menu item 3B. 2013, red</a>
  <br>
  <br>

</div>

<iframe width="100%" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```